# How can I improve my MS Excel formula?

Tags: excel

This is a code I wrote to check for shifts where an employee is given more than 5 days straight duty - which is not allowed. So wrote this to ensure that this won't happen. I know the code works but it looked horrible so I was wondering if how can I improve this?

Here are the parameters. I just want to count 73, 311, 711. The combinations of these must not exceed 5 straight days without offs in between.

Here's my code:

=IF(IF(COUNTIFS(B15:G15,"<>"&$Z$21,B15:G15,"<>VL",B15:G15,"<>LWOP")>5,COUNTIFS(B15:G15,"<>"&$Z$21,B15:G15,"<>VL",B15:G15,"<>LWOP"),0)+IF(COUNTIFS(C15:H15,"<>"&$Z$21,C15:H15,"<>VL",C15:H15,"<>LWOP")>5,COUNTIFS(C15:H15,"<>"&$Z$21,C15:H15,"<>VL",C15:H15,"<>LWOP"),0)+IF(COUNTIFS(D15:I15,"<>"&$Z$21,D15:I15,"<>VL",D15:I15,"<>LWOP")>5,COUNTIFS(D15:I15,"<>"&$Z$21,D15:I15,"<>VL",D15:I15,"<>LWOP"),0)+IF(COUNTIFS(E15:J15,"<>"&$Z$21,E15:J15,"<>VL",E15:J15,"<>LWOP")>5,COUNTIFS(E15:J15,"<>"&$Z$21,E15:J15,"<>VL",E15:J15,"<>LWOP"),0)+IF(COUNTIFS(F15:K15,"<>"&$Z$21,F15:K15,"<>VL",F15:K15,"<>LWOP")>5,COUNTIFS(F15:K15,"<>"&$Z$21,F15:K15,"<>VL",F15:K15,"<>LWOP"),0)+IF(COUNTIFS(G15:L15,"<>"&$Z$21,G15:L15,"<>VL",G15:L15,"<>LWOP")>5,COUNTIFS(G15:L15,"<>"&$Z$21,G15:L15,"<>VL",G15:L15,"<>LWOP"),0)+IF(COUNTIFS(H15:M15,"<>"&$Z$21,H15:M15,"<>VL",H15:M15,"<>LWOP")>5,COUNTIFS(H15:M15,"<>"&$Z$21,H15:M15,"<>VL",H15:M15,"<>LWOP"),0)+IF(COUNTIFS(I15:N15,"<>"&$Z$21,I15:N15,"<>VL",I15:N15,"<>LWOP")>5,COUNTIFS(I15:N15,"<>"&$Z$21,I15:N15,"<>VL",I15:N15,"<>LWOP"),0)+IF(COUNTIFS(J15:O15,"<>"&$Z$21,J15:O15,"<>VL",J15:O15,"<>LWOP")>5,COUNTIFS(J15:O15,"<>"&$Z$21,J15:O15,"<>VL",J15:O15,"<>LWOP"),0)+IF(COUNTIFS(K15:P15,"<>"&$Z$21,K15:P15,"<>VL",K15:P15,"<>LWOP")>5,COUNTIFS(K15:P15,"<>"&$Z$21,K15:P15,"<>VL",K15:P15,"<>LWOP"),0)+IF(COUNTIFS(L15:Q15,"<>"&$Z$21,L15:Q15,"<>VL",L15:Q15,"<>LWOP",L15:Q15,"<>"&" ")>5,COUNTIFS(L15:Q15,"<>"&$Z$21,L15:Q15,"<>VL",L15:Q15,"<>LWOP",L15:Q15,"<>"&" "),0)>0,"Error","")

[image]

Comment: What cell is this formula going in? Are you scanning for every 5 day period? Does a number with a subscript mean the employee is working? Does VL mean the employee is working? Does the rule reset every half month, or is working Nov 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one formula will result in TRUE if Employee 1 is scheduled for more than five consecutive days of duty:

```
=6>MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(ISNUMBER(B15:P15),COLUMN(B15:P15)),IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(B15:P15)),COLUMN(B15:P15))))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

No helper cells needed.

This works by making the assumption that duty codes are numeric, while every other code is not.

Comment: This is just brilliant but I will have to change all shifts from general format to a number format and will remove the subscripts. A small price to pay. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Break it up into two steps.  Make a bunch of cells that say:

```
B16=COUNTIFS(B15:G15,"<>"&$Z$21,B15:G15,"<>VL",B15:G15,"<>LWOP"
C16=COUNTIFS(C15:H15,"<>"&$Z$21,C15:H15,"<>VL",C15:H15,"<>LWOP"
D16=COUNTIFS(D15:I15,"<>"&$Z$21,D15:I15,"<>VL",D15:I15,"<>LWOP"
E16=COUNTIFS(E15:J15,"<>"&$Z$21,E15:J15,"<>VL",E15:J15,"<>LWOP"
F16=COUNTIFS(F15:K15,"<>"&$Z$21,F15:K15,"<>VL",F15:K15,"<>LWOP"
...
L16=COUNTIFS(L15:Q15,"<>"&$Z$21,L15:Q15,"<>VL",L15:Q15,"<>LWOP",L15:Q15,"<>"&" "
```

Then one to combine them:

```
=IF((B16>5,B16,0)
 +IF(C16>5,C16,0)
 +IF(D16>5,D16,0)
 +IF(E16>5,E16,0)
 ..
 +IF(L16>5,L16,0)>0,"Error","")
```